# Trouble installing BLAS, and the purpose of CMakeLists?

Tags: c++, cmake, blas

I am trying to install openBLAS for C++, to use in Visual Studio (2017) on windows 64bit. There is a step by step installation here https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/How-to-use-OpenBLAS-in-Microsoft-Visual-Studio.

When I get to step 6 and enter the command it comes back with the message: "CMake Error: The source directory *"directory name"* does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt."

I am not familiar with CMake files and have checked that all the correct packages are installed. I can create a CMakeLists.txt in the folder above but am not sure what to put in it/why it wouldn't add that as a step in the installation. Any advice?

Also when I type `link` into bash as instructed it says that are missing operands for that command. So I'm not sure if the environment is indeed active.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, there is a CMakeLists.txt already: https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/blob/develop/CMakeLists.txt

So where you got all the files, create a build folder, go in, and run the command. You can see that there is a `..` that will tell CMake to get the CMakeLists.txt from OpenBLAS.

Comment: So when it refers to 'configuring the project' is it referring to the project that you are trying to use BLAS in? Or is it saying that you should clone the BLAS repo and that this is the 'project' that you should be configuring?

Comment: You clone the repo (or download a tar.gz), and in this folder, you create `build`. Configuring the project is configuring OpenBLAS, as you need to build it first.